# Xcode crash on archived app validation

Tags: xcode, crash

I am trying to validate an iPhone app for submission through the organizer window in Xcode.
Xcode crashes and gives the following error message on attempting to validate:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[ITunesSoftwareApplicationDescription applicationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x400ab34e0
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff82fd126a __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff841e4d5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff8305d4ce -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff82fbe133 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff82fbdf48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x000000010dcbcc9b __block_global_8 (in IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer)
  6  0x00007fff82ffaed2 __NSArrayChunkIterate (in CoreFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff83056491 ____NSArrayGetIndexesPassingTest_block_invoke_1 (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff895d1467 _dispatch_apply_serial (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff895cf9d7 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff895d1347 dispatch_apply_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff895d1697 _dispatch_apply_slow (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff82fcc2d2 __NSArrayGetIndexesPassingTest (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x000000010dcbcaee __50-[AAVFetchApplicationListAssistant viewDidInstall]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer)
 14  0x00007fff895cd8ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff895ce799 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff8c7853da _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff8c786b85 start_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
```

Has anyone come acrss this?

Comment: I update Xcode by clicking the update in the application folder then validated the app and it worked

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26027417/1182823

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error and fixed it. it took me 1 full day with no success reading the forums, then i read ALL of apple papers on the subject (about 15-20 pages) and fixed them fairly quickly.

Your certificates are not in order. This is how its fixed: 1) have your distribution certificate available on your machine, and is selectable under code signing. (4.2.1 said distribution, and a provisioning profile that it can use. Once i fixed it, xcode stopped crashing, and validated with meaningful results.

david