# Xcode 6 crashes when validating or submitting app archive

Tags: ios, xcode

This worked fine 2 days ago using the exact same archive and provisioning profile (selected from the organizer). Anyone else seeing this? I haven't updated Xcode, so it seems like it might be something on Apple's end causing a failure?

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A313
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6299/IDEFoundation/Issues/IDEIssueManager.m:457
Details:  This method must only be called on the main thread
Object:   <IDEIssueManager>
Method:   +_issueProviderInfo
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa1abfa8e60>{name = (null), num = 44}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001027adf0a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010156dbaf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010156de9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000101ea2bce +[IDEIssueManager _issueProviderInfo] (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x0000000101ea224d -[IDEIssueManager _updateIssueProviders] (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x000000010157ffbe __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x00000001014fa6c8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x00000001013ae124 -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff8aed8f28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff8aed80f8 NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff8aedcbe6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8ddf3f6f doSetValuesInSourceWithKVO (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff8ddf3e0f _CFXPreferencesReplaceValuesInNamedVolatileSource (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff8b07fafc -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in Foundation)
 14  0x00000001124ad9e9 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) REPLACEMENT_setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 15  0x00000001124a3fac -[MZJSONServiceClient connectionDidFinishLoading:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 16  0x00007fff8af877fd __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke (in Foundation)
 17  0x00007fff8af8772d -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] (in Foundation)
 18  0x00007fff8af8761c -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] (in Foundation)
 19  0x00007fff989e9284 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 20  0x00007fff98a9f820 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 (in CFNetwork)
 21  0x00007fff989cc2ec ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 22  0x00007fff8de04a94 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff989cc1cb RunloopBlockContext::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 24  0x00007fff989cc073 MultiplexerSource::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 25  0x00007fff989cbea2 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) (in CFNetwork)
 26  0x00007fff8de395b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 27  0x00007fff8de2ac62 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation)
 28  0x00007fff8de2a3ef __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 29  0x00007fff8de29e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 30  0x00007fff8af38adc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] (in Foundation)
 31  0x00007fff8af8110b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] (in Foundation)
 32  0x00000001124a3468 -[MZJSONServiceClient getResultDictionary] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 33  0x00000001124a55da -[MZLabelServiceClient invokeSOAPCall] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 34  0x00000001124aa904 -[MZWebServiceOperationWorker execute] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 35  0x00000001124aac02 -[MZWebServiceWorker run] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 36  0x000000011248336c -[MZWorkItem main] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 37  0x00007fff8aed78a1 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 38  0x00007fff8aed754b __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 39  0x00007fff96f8528d _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 40  0x00007fff96f897e3 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 41  0x00007fff96f8528d _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 42  0x00007fff96f87082 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 43  0x00007fff96f88177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 44  0x00007fff934d0ef8 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 45  0x00007fff934d3fb9 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue as well. I did not have any problem a couple days before.

Comment: Got the same problem. I just submitted one application last week without any problem.

Comment: Why haven't you updated Xcode?

Comment: got the same issue. It is ok 2 days ago.

Comment: By user3768574: *"Our Apple contact told us he'd heard something about this and to keep trying."* I guess it's really an issue from Apple's end. **NOTE: Unless anyone can provide correct information/workaround, please don't use answer to "comment". Answers are for real answers only**.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be pretty widespread: https://twitter.com/marcoarment/status/511636271434043392

Comment: Same issue. Did not have a problem 4 days ago.

Comment: Same problem here. Started to manifest yesterday. I successfully uploaded 6 builds, but yesterday and today I wasn't able to upload a new binary. I regenerated the certificates, appid and provisioning profile several times with no success.

Comment: Same issue but different solution there: Close Xcode and keep Organizer open. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898566/xcode-crashes-on-submitting-archive

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Make sure you've accepted all of the new agreements in the Member Center.

To check if you need to, you can go to the preferences -> accounts in XCode, and chose to *view details* of an account and attempt to *refresh* using the little button. Here, XCode will warn you that you need to accept new agreements in the Member Center before you can refresh.

On the other hand, the Organizer will just crash instead of warning you about un-signed agreements.

Comment: That's the perfect solution in my case

Comment: This seems to be the issue. Sounds like Apple needs to update Xcode to handle this situation a little better.

Comment: just crazy how Apple lets this kind of bug to happen.

Answer (score 30):

I solved the problem by:

1. Export the ipa in organiser
2. Using Application Loader to load the ipa to app store

Comment: Seems like the community is very active at the moment getting ready for iOS 8 :)

Comment: this works, but cannot submit the symbols along with the IPA to App Store for crash report analysis.

Comment: Symbols can be submitted, you have to export for app store and check the symbols check box

Comment: Also for me that is the only way to submit app

Comment: Ended up doing the same today (see datestamp). Exact same error dump as OP and none of the other suggested solutions worked. It's incredible they let this error persist.

Answer (score 29):

I found solution/workaround on https://devforums.apple.com/.
Post by 優 Yu:

> "Open the Organizer by performing Arches. Please close the only xcode
>   body. Please do not close the Organizer screen. Please go and Submit
>   Validation in that state. I'm glad If we can help you."

Works for me, but after validation I got strange message:

> "The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to
>   validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an
>   informational message.".

I ignored it and successfully submitted app to App Store. Looks like Apple broke their validation system, because I submitted an app 5 days ago without any problems.

Comment: Goodness. Thanks for this. It worked for me. The solution is to have _only_ the Archives window open (close all the rest).

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on June 17, 2015.

Comment: ios dev/ xcode inconsistencies are absolutely unbelievable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it looks like apple just withdrew the option to upload with XCode 6. Either use XCode 5.1.1 or Applauncher 2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Simply Accept the new License and Agreement in developer.apple.com 's Member Center.

Answer (score 1):

I have used bagusflyer's workaround to submit app, but finally I found out how to solve it permanently.

Here is the solution:

1. Accept new changed terms and condition from [apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). (Just like Sandeep said)
2. Go to [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) to generate new provision profiles, for App Store & AdHoc ([Tutorial](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/iphone6-6-and-ios8-xcode6-first-hand-on-experience-with-unity.269422/))
3. Double click new provision profiles you downloaded to install them, and then XCode will never crash.

The problem is caused by XCode 6.0 does not handle provision profile migration properly. Developers should regenerate provision profiles for XCode 6+, but Xcode 6.0 fails to display this error message properly and crashes. (If you use XCode 6.1 Beta, it will display error messages for you, no crash. Then you will know that the problem is caused by "invalid"=="legacy" provision profile.)

After that, you can submit app and export Ad Hoc distribution for Testflight.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the other suggestions, no success.

Finally I removed my AppleID from the accounts preferences pane and re-added it.
That did the trick!

Since then, app submission was working again.

Comment: I tried same with xcode6.0 and xcode6.1 but still getting issue. Unable to generate adhoc file.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. Is it an apple server issue? NO success with re-adding.

Answer (score 0):

For me, The problem seems to happen because of uploading same build to the submission. Try to change the Build Number (not a Version number) then upload again.

Comment: did that, no success tho

Comment: Sometimes, you still have to use Application Loader. I guess that Organizer in GM is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by accepting new license agreement in the Member's Center.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple projects opened while archiving, closing all others worked.

Answer (score 0):

4 hours wasted last night with unknown error, didn't even get an error until opened Xcode > Organiser, closed Xcode, then uploaded. Still no joy, moved to Application loader and then hit further errors. Finally upload worked when given the Agent account details, no joy with my Admin account details.

Answer (score 0):

These steps works with Xcode 7.x:

- close Xcode
- launch Disk Utility, make a First Aid to your OSX disk
- open Xcode, go to Window - Project and clean your project Derived Data
- open Window - Organizer
- open Xcode - Preferences - Account and remove and re-add your account
- launch your project
- go to both project and target - Build settings - Build Options (settings) and set "Enable Bitcode" to NO ( if your project don't use bitcode)
- select a real device and build and run your project to the device
- go to product and launch archive