# Xcode 6 always crashes when validating or submitting an app to the App Store

Tags: xcode, validation, submit

Has anyone faced the same problem? Xcode 6 always crashes when validating or submitting an app to the App Store

Error log

```
Process:         Xcode [8131] Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:         6.0 (6299) Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6299000000000000~8 Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [953] Responsible:     Xcode [8131] User ID:  501

Date/Time:       2014-09-16 11:17:25.896 +0700 OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28) Report Version:  11 Anonymous UUID:  000105CF-23BA-628A-BB6A-49EE41B0CD85

Sleep/Wake UUID: B292739C-BD69-46FE-A5BE-87924AFB5243

Crashed Thread:  11  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7ff2237695c0

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 6A313 ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6299/IDEFoundation/Issues/IDEIssueManager.m:457 Details:  This method must only be called on the main thread Object:   <IDEIssueManager> Method:   +_issueProviderInfo Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff224a7eaf0>{name = (null), num = 20} Hints:   None Backtrace:   0  0x0000000104b84f0a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)   1  0x0000000103944baf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)   2  0x0000000103944e9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)   3  0x0000000104279bce +[IDEIssueManager
_issueProviderInfo] (in IDEFoundation)   4  0x000000010427924d -[IDEIssueManager _updateIssueProviders] (in IDEFoundation)   5  0x0000000103956fbe __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)   6  0x00000001038d16c8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership (in DVTFoundation)   7  0x0000000103785124 -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)   8  0x00007fff8cbfff28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)   9  0x00007fff8cbff0f8 NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)  10  0x00007fff8cc03be6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)  11  0x00007fff9001cf6f doSetValuesInSourceWithKVO (in CoreFoundation)  12  0x00007fff9001ce0f
_CFXPreferencesReplaceValuesInNamedVolatileSource (in CoreFoundation)  13  0x00007fff8cda6afc -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in Foundation)  14  0x0000000118ff49e9
-[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) REPLACEMENT_setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  15  0x0000000118feafac -[MZJSONServiceClient connectionDidFinishLoading:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  16  0x00007fff8ccae7fd __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal
_withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke (in Foundation)  17  0x00007fff8ccae72d -[NSURLConnectionInternal
_withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] (in Foundation)  18  0x00007fff8ccae61c -[NSURLConnectionInternal
_withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] (in Foundation)  19  0x00007fff8711b224
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)  20  0x00007fff8719fd60
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 (in CFNetwork)  21  0x00007fff870fe28c
___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)  22  0x00007fff9002da94 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)  23  0x00007fff870fe16b RunloopBlockContext::perform() (in CFNetwork)  24  0x00007fff870fe013 MultiplexerSource::perform() (in CFNetwork)  25  0x00007fff870fde42 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) (in CFNetwork)  26  0x00007fff900625b1
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)  27  0x00007fff90053c62 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation)  28  0x00007fff900533ef __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)  29  0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)  30  0x00007fff8cc5fadc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] (in Foundation)  31  0x00007fff8cca810b
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] (in Foundation)  32  0x0000000118fea468 -[MZJSONServiceClient getResultDictionary] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  33  0x0000000118fec5da
-[MZLabelServiceClient invokeSOAPCall] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  34  0x0000000118ff1904 -[MZWebServiceOperationWorker execute] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  35  0x0000000118ff1c02 -[MZWebServiceWorker run] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  36  0x0000000118fca36c -[MZWorkItem main] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)  37  0x00007fff8cbfe8a1
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)  38  0x00007fff8cbfe54b __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)  39  0x00007fff8f00928d _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)  40 0x00007fff8f00d7e3 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)  41  0x00007fff8f00928d _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)  42  0x00007fff8f00b082
_dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)  43  0x00007fff8f00c177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)  44 0x00007fff87094ef8 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)  45  0x00007fff87097fb9 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)   abort() called

Application Specific Signatures: [NSThread isMainThread]

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff9086aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff90869d18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053f15
__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation   0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.HIToolbox   0x00007fff8c165a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226 6   com.apple.HIToolbox              0x00007fff8c1657b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479 7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c1655bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65 8   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff88ea424e _DPSNextEvent
+ 1434 9   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff88ea389b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122 10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit               0x0000000103eaa7bd -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237 11  com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff88e9799c -[NSApplication run]
+ 553 12  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff88e82783 NSApplicationMain + 940 13  libdyld.dylib                    0x00007fff8ad605fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff9086f662 kevent64 + 10 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8f00b421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
+ 239 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f00b136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib   0x00007fff9086aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff90869d18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90053539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cc5d967 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348 6   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8cc5d76b
__NSThread__main__ + 1318 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff9086e9aa __select + 10 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff9009fa03 __CFSocketManager + 867 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start
+ 13

Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff9086aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff90869d18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90053539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cc5fadc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253 6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase      0x000000011190e1d2
-[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 676 7   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8cc5d76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899
_pthread_body + 138 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff9086aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff90869d18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90053539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cc5fadc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253 6   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8cd484aa
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74 7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation 0x0000000113cce9eb
-[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134 8   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cc5d76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899
_pthread_body + 138 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff9086aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff90869d18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90053539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8904405e _NSEventThread + 144 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff9086e716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87095c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010d53fb0e -[XCBlockQueue
_processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519 3   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8cc5d76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start
+ 13

Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff9086e716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87095c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010d53fb0e -[XCBlockQueue
_processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519 3   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8cc5d76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start
+ 13

Thread 9: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff9086e716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87095c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010d53fb0e -[XCBlockQueue
_processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519 3   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8cc5d76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start
+ 13

Thread 10:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9086ea3a __semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff8877cdc0 nanosleep + 200 2   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8cca72f2 +[NSThread sleepUntilDate:] + 176 3   com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesSoftwareService 0x000000011959ce69
-[ITunesSoftwareServiceImpl applicationWithAttributesWorker:operationPtr:workSeriesPtr:] + 316 4   com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesSoftwareService   0x000000011959e452
-[ITunesSoftwareServiceImpl validateApplicationArchiveAtPath:authenticationServiceResponse:] + 430 5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit              0x0000000104e87a91
+[AAVITunesConnectProxy validateApplicationArchiveAtPath:usingSession:] + 150 6   com.apple.dt.IDEKit               0x0000000104e5a743
__61-[IDEDistributionValidationStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke + 482 7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x000000010397cbac __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 106 8   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8f00c1bb
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 9   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f00928d _dispatch_client_callout + 8 10  libdispatch.dylib   0x00007fff8f00b082 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326 11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8f00c177
_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff87094ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87097fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7ff2237695c0 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff9086e866 __pthread_kill + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709435c pthread_kill + 92 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff8875db1a abort + 125 3 com.apple.dt.IDEKit            0x0000000104b84ae6
+[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:]
+ 1510 4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit              0x0000000104b850c0 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
+ 1169 5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation       0x0000000103944baf _DVTAssertionHandler + 367 6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x0000000103944e9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407 7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation     0x0000000104279bce +[IDEIssueManager
_issueProviderInfo] + 1005 8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation       0x000000010427924d -[IDEIssueManager _updateIssueProviders] + 426 9   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x0000000103956fbe
__73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke + 83 10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001038d16c8 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 75 11  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x0000000103785124 -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 576 12  com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8cbfff28 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 387 13  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cbff0f8 NSKeyValueDidChange + 453 14  com.apple.Foundation   0x00007fff8cc03be6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 118 15  com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff9001cf6f doSetValuesInSourceWithKVO + 335 16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9001ce0f
_CFXPreferencesReplaceValuesInNamedVolatileSource + 111 17  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8cda6afc
-[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setVolatileDomain:forName:] + 21 18  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation  0x0000000118ff49e9
-[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) REPLACEMENT_setVolatileDomain:forName:] + 29 19  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation   0x0000000118feafac
-[MZJSONServiceClient connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 657 20  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8ccae7fd
__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 48 21  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ccae72d
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 244 22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ccae61c
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 69 23  com.apple.CFNetwork               0x00007fff8711b224
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104 24  com.apple.CFNetwork              0x00007fff8719fd60 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2
+ 84 25  com.apple.CFNetwork            0x00007fff870fe28c ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke
+ 25 26  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff9002da94 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68 27  com.apple.CFNetwork            0x00007fff870fe16b RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 115 28  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff870fe013 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 269 29  com.apple.CFNetwork               0x00007fff870fde42 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72 30  com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff900625b1
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17 31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90053c62
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242 32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff900533ef __CFRunLoopRun + 831 33  com.apple.CoreFoundation    0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 34  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cc5fadc
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253 35  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cca810b
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 78 36  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation 0x0000000118fea468
-[MZJSONServiceClient getResultDictionary] + 472 37  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation   0x0000000118fec5da
-[MZLabelServiceClient invokeSOAPCall] + 19 38  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation    0x0000000118ff1904
-[MZWebServiceOperationWorker execute] + 46 39  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation    0x0000000118ff1c02
-[MZWebServiceWorker run] + 121 40  com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation    0x0000000118fca36c
-[MZWorkItem main] + 311 41  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8cbfe8a1 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 631 42  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8cbfe54b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64 43  libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8f00928d
_dispatch_client_callout + 8 44  libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8f00d7e3 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 154 45  libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8f00928d
_dispatch_client_callout + 8 46  libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8f00b082 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326 47  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8f00c177
_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40 48  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff87094ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314 49  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87097fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff9086ee6a
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87094f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87097fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff9086ee6a
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87094f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87097fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff9086ee6a
__workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87094f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87097fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:: com.apple.appkit-heartbeat 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       0x00007fff9086ea3a __semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib          0x00007fff8877cdc0 nanosleep + 200 2   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8877ccb2 usleep + 54 3   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff8910817d -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 2132 4   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff8cc5d76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899
_pthread_body + 138 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 16: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff9086aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff90869d18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90053f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90053539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff90052e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff90108811 CFRunLoopRun + 97 6   com.apple.DebugSymbols         0x00007fff8e5fd7e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start
+ 13

Thread 17: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff9086ea3a
__semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8877cdc0 nanosleep + 200 2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication      0x00007fff87eae481 cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 42 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff87093899 _pthread_body + 138 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8709372a _pthread_start + 137 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87097fc9 thread_start
+ 13

Thread 11 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000011587b000  rcx: 0x0000000115878c38  rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000009d1b  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000000115878c60  rsp: 0x0000000115878c38   r8: 0x0000000000003fff   r9: 0xffff800ddb58150f  r10: 0x000000000c000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206   r12: 0x00007fff8c6af0d0  r13: 0x00007ff22485e1c0  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007ff225ba6000   rip: 0x00007fff9086e866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000108adc000    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:      0x02000148 Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x103778000 -        0x103778ff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (6.0 - 6299) <B05D487B-F21A-3E33-8E16-59AD472578B7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x10377d000 -        0x103bb0ff7  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (6.0 - 6271) <DEE402AC-A4CD-3BA7-B1DA-C2EE0C35C46A> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x103d6a000 -        0x104071fff  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (6.0 - 6271) <1CDBF9FE-63F5-3226-B810-5ADA7B1854B0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x104255000 -        0x104682fff  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (6.0 - 6299) <9830F38E-1090-349E-9E8F-FF1E9EA14E18> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x104937000 -        0x105171ff7  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (6.0 - 6299) <03597575-67D1-3ECB-94E3-DA5B69FB0D91> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x105712000 -        0x10572fff7  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices (1.0 - 56085) <E7CD337D-F164-3DC0-A94D-6AFE017988E3> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/Versions/A/DTXConnectionServices
       0x105750000 -        0x10578cfff  com.apple.framework.ConfigurationProfiles (6.0.2 - 667) <6AEA891F-CA82-3DB2-B2B5-735713FF618C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConfigurationProfiles.framework/Versions/A/ConfigurationProfiles
       0x1057b0000 -        0x1057b1ffb  libsysmon.dylib (58.90.2) <86ECDE0C-6022-3138-AD95-293098B617B7> /usr/lib/libsysmon.dylib
       0x1057bd000 -        0x10624efff +libclang.dylib (600.0.51) <C234F51B-1C1E-391C-9A17-C987D112F431>
```

Comment: using application loader also not fix (0 byte/sec)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a problem in Apple's end, since many people have experienced this while a few days ago it all worked flawlessly.

[Xcode 6 crashes when validating or submitting app archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858977/xcode-6-crashes-when-validating-or-submitting-app-archive)

EDIT:
Just confirmed that exporting and using App Loader solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to when Xcode won't upload to the App Store:

1. Export from organizer and saved the .ipa file.
2. Upload to store with Application Loader.

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've accepted all of the new agreements in the Member Center.

see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26027417/258795

Answer (score 0):

Use an old Xcode 5.x or Application Loader for the moment