# Xcode 6 crashes on submitting Archive

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Today I uploaded my first build of first app successfully to App Store for beta testing. After making a few changes, when I tried to submit the new archive again Xcode crashed, and still crashes.

It's the log:

```
Process:               Xcode [36810]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.2 (7718)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7718000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812404257
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [36810]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-17 21:59:26.432 +0430
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        A70B5585-6ADF-B647-C184-94420293DB9F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       536542A5-38C8-405F-8A5E-28DBE775C033

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       18000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fdb9771af00 :: NSOperation 0x7fdb97679160 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEFoundation/Issues/IDEIssueManager.m:457
Details:  This method must only be called on the main thread
Object:   <IDEIssueManager>
Method:   +_issueProviderInfo
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fdb971db920>{number = 80, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000102e28b6a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x0000000101b765df _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000101b768ce _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001024f248e +[IDEIssueManager _issueProviderInfo] (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x00000001024f1b0d -[IDEIssueManager _updateIssueProviders] (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x0000000101b893de __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x0000000101afed5c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x00000001019b03e4 -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff8a8af0f3 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff8a8bbd68 NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff8a87497d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8befddaf doSetValuesInSourceWithKVO (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff8befdc46 _CFXPreferencesReplaceValuesInNamedVolatileSource (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff8aa4b027 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in Foundation)
 14  0x0000000119e34a13 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) REPLACEMENT_setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 15  0x0000000119e34f87 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) synchronizeRegistrationDomains] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 16  0x0000000119e34d5d -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) registerPriorityDefaults:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 17  0x0000000119e2669e -[MZJSONServiceClient processApplicationSettings:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 18  0x0000000119e26d7d -[MZJSONServiceClient connectionDidFinishLoading:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 19  0x00007fff8846d24d __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 20  0x00007fff8846d0b1 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] (in CFNetwork)
 21  0x00007fff8846cfb7 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] (in CFNetwork)
 22  0x00007fff8846df74 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 23  0x00007fff88521703 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 (in CFNetwork)
 24  0x00007fff883c2cec RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) (in CFNetwork)
 25  0x00007fff8bf0e664 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff883c2bad RunloopBlockContext::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 27  0x00007fff883c2998 MultiplexerSource::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 28  0x00007fff883c27ba MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) (in CFNetwork)
 29  0x00007fff8bf42a01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 30  0x00007fff8bf34b8d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation)
 31  0x00007fff8bf341bf __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 32  0x00007fff8bf33bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 33  0x00007fff8a8fda59 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] (in Foundation)
 34  0x00007fff8a91bcce -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] (in Foundation)
 35  0x0000000119e25d00 -[MZJSONServiceClient getResultDictionary] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 36  0x0000000119e28eb3 -[MZLabelServiceClient invokeSOAPCall] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 37  0x0000000119e3097d -[MZWebServiceOperationWorker execute] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 38  0x0000000119e30e11 -[MZWebServiceWorker run] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 39  0x0000000119df854d -[MZWorkItem main] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 40  0x00007fff8a8c6a6c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 41  0x00007fff8a8c6543 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 42  0x00007fff89468c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 43  0x00007fff8946c365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 44  0x00007fff8946decc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 45  0x00007fff8946b6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 46  0x00007fff89479fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 47  0x00007fff86f91637 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 48  0x00007fff86f8f40d start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

**Note:** I can validate the Archive without error.

Will re-installing XCode help me to fix it?

Comment: same issue, solved closing project's windows as others suggested below. Only i could not validate the archive: the window stuck with the "Validation in progress message..."

Comment: @Dunc, I also had this problem (only showed up today) and it wasn't the same problem as the one in your link. The answer below solved my problem.

Comment: It looks like Apple were updating their site, as its now working again!

Comment: This question probably related with this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30899865/4145420

Comment: Has anyone filed this bug with stack trace with Apple? They'd probably really like to see it!

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Close any projects or workspace windows you have open in Xcode but leave Organizer window open and re-submit worked for me.

Comment: Uploads were working two days ago. Today, uploads were crashing. Updated Xcode from 6.3 to 6.3.2. Wiped out build folder, and rebuilt everything from scratch with 6.3.2. Uploading still crashed. Have two identities/accounts tied to Xcode. One of the accounts needed to accept latest agreement, accepted the agreement. Re-synced the account with Xcode. Uploading still crashed. Only closing the Xcode project, leaving the Organizer window up, and submitting in this fashion worked to upload the archive. Thank you Sami! huge +1

Comment: great catch!  seems like itunes connect has also been having a rough go of it today.  Apple needs to pull some guys off the "Re-Invent Spotify" team and get them on this...

Comment: The 'close Xcode windows' trick worked for me - but remember to also close any minimized or hidden Xcode windows as well. Close ALL Xcode windows, in other words, and you'll save yourself hours of pain.

Comment: Silly me, I thought you have to quit Xcode with the organizer window open. You actually have to quit your project, but leave the Xcode app open. Then it works for some reason!

Comment: This wording is confusing. It is important to remember not to *quit* Xcode, as Xcode itself still has to be open. I'm fairly certain this answer is actually suggesting to close any open projects/workspaces. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Has anyone raised a RADAR with Apple? Also looks like the Developer site has just updated, so maybe they've been doing something?

Comment: Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Worked for me but I also had to open Photo Booth and Numbers while holding Cmd+Option+Shift+a+p+l and click the apple logo in the task bar 7 times before uploading

Comment: Worked for me as well! Just close the projects and leave the organizer open to submit. Then it uploads without crashing. Must be a damn stupid bug.

Comment: You can also export as AppStore build and upload with Application Loader.

Comment: Off topic: But quite confusing seeing that guy's reputation is only 934 when this answer has 392 uproots which means his reputation should at least ~3k! Is this is a bug on SO?

Answer (score 52):

Just got this problem. Seems to work if you close all other Xcode windows but keep the organizer window open.

Answer (score 17):

Had the same problem - uploaded my .ipa through the Application Loader.

Answer (score 11):

The original question is: "Will re-installing XCode help me to fix it?" 
The answer is: "No." Re-installation does not help the problem. The bug is pretty serious though, since submitting an app is central to app development. A fix should be in the App Store asap. Hence updating later may help.

Comment: Just restart your entire os maybe? At least that's apples first line support answer for any problem :-D        PS: don't actually do this, sami's answer seems to work

Comment: @nsij22 Restart the entire os doesn't work ... It is the second method I tried, right after restarting Xcode ...

Comment: I tried re-start both before & after the update; these changes had no effect on submissions. I agree with you @nsij22; Sami's method is the only one that works.

Comment: Successfully submitting a build did not require re-installation or a new update today; leaving an Xcode window open did not hinder the submission in any way.

Answer (score 10):

Following steps worked for me:

1. Archive the project.
2. Open Organizer
3. Press the top-left cross button of XCode which will close all projects without quiting XCode and Organiser will be opened
4. Now resubmit the archive from organiser.

Answer (score 7):

Had this problem today. I was only able to successfully upload the Archive when the organizer window was open and all Xcode projects were closed.

Answer (score 6):

I created an .ipa file using the Export utility in Organizer, then ran Application Loader. Selected the 'Deliver Your App' button. Choose the new created ipa file and the file appeared in iTuneConnect under the pre-release tab as expected for TestFlight distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem today. Problem turned out I still had the Reveal Framework included in my project. Make sure you don't have any non-public API usage in your archive.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered similar situation. However, my solution was somehow different.

Noticing that you are trying to submit next build, please make sure your previous build is excluded from App Store submit form before uploading new build.

I'm not sure why this has to be an issue, but it seems like that the submit form should be cleared before receiving new build.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to accept some new user agreements, try going to [Apple Developer Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) and see if they're any new agreements you need to accept.

If that doesn't work try this: open Xcode and go to [ Preferences ] -> [ Accounts ], select your Apple ID and click on [ View Details... ]. Once you do that click on the refresh icon at the bottom left. If you're missing anything it will let you know.

If both of those don't work go back to the archive window in XCode and click on export on the right-hand side underneath the submit button. Save it where ever you want but remember the location. Once exported go back to XCode and go to [ Open Developer Tools ] -> [ Application Loader ]. You can submit your new version of your app through that.

If none of those work then I have no idea, maybe someone else knows.

Comment: It wasn't the user agreements for me, but the comment about opening preferences was helpful - turns out it was this simple: my session had expired!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue at June 17 night. I reinstalled my Xcode, and had the same issue. Looks like Apple updated something at that day, since I noticed the website of Member Center, the MAC certificate is also there. (YES!!! apple only charge once for iPhone and Mac)

Answer (score 3):

If that doesn't work, than it could also be that the used Certificate has expired. So check if your Certificate is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Archive using Xcode 6.4, submit using Xcode 7. Submission successful