# During Ad Hoc distribution Xcode Crashed

Tags: ios, xcode6.3

During Ad Hoc distribution Xcode app was crashed. I have tried doing Ad Hoc using different system but still Xcode app is still crashing. I have attached the crash log below.

```
Crashed Thread:        17  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fb20c902630 :: NSOperation 0x7fb210a433c0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D570
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7569/IDEFoundation/Issues/IDEIssueManager.m:457
Details:  This method must only be called on the main thread
Object:   <IDEIssueManager>
Method:   +_issueProviderInfo
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb20cbdc520>{number = 40, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010ac42bfa -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010999bbaf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010999be9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010a31142e +[IDEIssueManager _issueProviderInfo] (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x000000010a310aad -[IDEIssueManager _updateIssueProviders] (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x00000001099ae9ae __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010992656c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x00000001097d7a24 -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff8ed69c73 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff8ed68e48 NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff8ed6d9ad -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff9592b92f doSetValuesInSourceWithKVO (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff9592b7c6 _CFXPreferencesReplaceValuesInNamedVolatileSource (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff8ef1ac57 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in Foundation)
 14  0x0000000155822a13 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) REPLACEMENT_setVolatileDomain:forName:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 15  0x0000000155822f87 -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) synchronizeRegistrationDomains] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 16  0x0000000155822d5d -[NSUserDefaults(ITunesConnectFoundationExtensions) registerPriorityDefaults:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 17  0x000000015581469e -[MZJSONServiceClient processApplicationSettings:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 18  0x0000000155814d7d -[MZJSONServiceClient connectionDidFinishLoading:] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 19  0x00007fff9243d24d __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 20  0x00007fff9243d1f1 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] (in CFNetwork)
 21  0x00007fff9243d357 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] (in CFNetwork)
 22  0x00007fff9230def4 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke (in CFNetwork)
 23  0x00007fff923d73b3 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 (in CFNetwork)
 24  0x00007fff922f97cc RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) (in CFNetwork)
 25  0x00007fff9593c1e4 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff922f968d RunloopBlockContext::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 27  0x00007fff922f952e MultiplexerSource::perform() (in CFNetwork)
 28  0x00007fff922f9350 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) (in CFNetwork)
 29  0x00007fff95970661 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 30  0x00007fff959627ed __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation)
 31  0x00007fff95961e1f __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 32  0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 33  0x00007fff8edcaab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] (in Foundation)
 34  0x00007fff8ee117ae -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] (in Foundation)
 35  0x0000000155813d00 -[MZJSONServiceClient getResultDictionary] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 36  0x0000000155816eb3 -[MZLabelServiceClient invokeSOAPCall] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 37  0x000000015581e97d -[MZWebServiceOperationWorker execute] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 38  0x000000015581ee11 -[MZWebServiceWorker run] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 39  0x00000001557e654d -[MZWorkItem main] (in ITunesConnectFoundation)
 40  0x00007fff8ed6859c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 41  0x00007fff8ed681a3 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 42  0x00007fff95ea8c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 43  0x00007fff95eac365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 44  0x00007fff95eadecc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 45  0x00007fff95eab6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 46  0x00007fff95eb9fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 47  0x00007fff91f826cb _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 48  0x00007fff91f804a1 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
[NSThread isMainThread]

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9281b43f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9281b1ba ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9281affb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91397821 _DPSNextEvent + 964
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91396fd0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000109f1edda -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9138af73 -[NSApplication run] + 594
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91376424 NSApplicationMain + 1832
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8f7675c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385722e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eaba6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9237de90 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff938563f6 __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385156a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eb2b9c _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 218
2   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000109948e1c DVTFutureWaitUntilAllFinished + 37
3   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001147e1782 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceToken _updatePrimaryConnection] + 1267
4   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001147e1f3b -[DTDKRemoteDeviceToken addConnection:] + 704
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001147cec1c __39-[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener _rescan]_block_invoke + 1382
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9597054c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962655 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962196 __CFRunLoopRun + 1814
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edcaab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
11  com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001147cdf2c -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 974
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edcaab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x00000001147bf8c6 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 213
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff914fa8f7 _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edcaab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8eec645f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011aa3c89b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000114196406 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000114196406 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000114196406 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8edc8b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95962b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95961838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95a17ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff970aab8f SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 463
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112d13049 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112d1469a lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 90
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112c6f3e7 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 327
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112c6f4fb lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112d857e0 ProcessGDBRemote::AsyncThread(void*) + 1228
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112d13049 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112d1469a lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 90
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112c6f3e7 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 327
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112c6f4d9 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventForBroadcaster(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 25
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112e37c0f lldb_private::Process::WaitForEventsPrivate(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&, bool) + 101
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112e3ed64 lldb_private::Process::RunPrivateStateThread() + 226
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000112e3e935 lldb_private::Process::PrivateStateThread(void*) + 9
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f822fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f82279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856486 __semwait_signal + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ee10a06 +[NSThread sleepUntilDate:] + 175
2   com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation    0x00000001557e534f +[MZAuthorizationTokenManager authorizationTokenForDefaultHostnameAndAppIdKeyWithUsername:password:error:] + 435
3   com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesSoftwareService  0x000000015468e282 -[ITunesSoftwareServiceImpl authorizationTokenForDefaultHostnameAndAppIdKeyWithUsername:password:error:] + 57
4   com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesSoftwareService  0x0000000154690867 -[ITunesSoftwareServiceImpl uploadApplicationArchiveAtPath:username:password:delegate:userInfo:] + 322
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001099818ac +[DVTITunesConnectProxy uploadApplicationArchiveAtPath:application:username:password:willBeginCallback:updatePercentageCallback:updateMessageCallback:shouldContinueCallback:didCompleteCallback:] + 525
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010998164f +[DVTITunesConnectProxy uploadApplicationArchiveAtPath:username:password:willBeginCallback:updatePercentageCallback:updateMessageCallback:shouldContinueCallback:didCompleteCallback:] + 189
7   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010afacb29 __57-[IDEDistributionUploadStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke127 + 842
8   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001099d4ccc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 106
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95ead323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95ea8c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eab88f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 935
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eb9fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f826cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:: Dispatch queue: parsing queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9385156a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eafc55 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 213
2   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010b814d7a -[DTXMessageParser waitForMoreData:incrementalBuffer:] + 87
3   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010b8149b8 -[DTXMessageParser parseMessage] + 50
4   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010b814776 __43-[DTXMessageParser initWithMessageHandler:]_block_invoke + 35
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95ead323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95ea8c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eac365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eadecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eab6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95eb9fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f826cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93856946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91f804a1 start_wqthread + 13
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I have restarted my MAC and Ad Hoc distribution was successfully done. But still can anyone let me know why Xcode was crashing in my previous Ad Hoc distribution.

Comment: this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898566/xcode-6-crashes-on-submitting-archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restarted my MAC and Ad Hoc distribution was successfully done.