# xCode crashes when submitting app on El Capitan beta 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, osx-elcapitan

**NOTE**: This will look like a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898566/xcode-6-crashes-on-submitting-archive), but none of the solutions in that question have solved it. I am almost certain this is an elcap beta 5 issue, as it was not happening on beta 4.

**The problem**: When I attempt to upload a fresh build to iTunes connect from the organizer window, xCode crashes.

**Details**: It is xCode 6.4, the App Store version, not beta. The 'Submit to App Store', 'Validate', and 'Export' buttons all cause crashes. When I click each of these, the dialog for choosing a development team appears, and when I click 'choose', xCode crashes. The build number is higher than the last submission, and there are no build errors, etc.

I have attempted closing all windows except the organizer, I have tried a reboot, and I have tried the beta version of 6.4 from the dev portal; none of these things work. I have not tried xCode 7 beta, but that would be useless to me as I need to submit the build to Test Flight.

My app's release is time-sensitive, so if anyone could help me find a workaround, that would be very helpful :)

Comment: Are you sure developers can submit app through Beta OS X?

Comment: @rohan-patel I'm not sure I understand your question. Am I allowed to submit iOS apps while using a beta version of OS X? Yes. I have been doing that for weeks. Am I allowed to submit iOS apps using a beta version of Xcode? Yes, but that build will not be eligible for test flight or the App Store.

Comment: "Am I allowed to submit iOS apps while using a beta version of OS X?" I was wondering about that. Thanks. I was under impression that under Beta OS X you can't submit apps.

Comment: And anyway, it's a beta version of OS X, so anything can happen. Including crashes in applications. There's a big warning about that.

Comment: You can *submit* an app using xCode 7; however, you can't *compile* it (for submission) using a beta version. This workaround also lets you test Swift 1.2 code on iOS 9.

Comment: @FrancisJervis even when compiling with Xcode6 and submitting with xcode7 triggers "Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK." on Submit for review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Archive it with Xcode 6 and then open up Xcode 7 and submit the archive from there.

Works for me

Comment: ditto, submission successful

Comment: Are you sure you can "submit submit"?   Have you tried hitting the "Submit for Review" yet?

Comment: it doesn't work for me, i got this message : Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: I am building and submitting from Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan and getting @user2724028's same error message in iTunes Connect

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be an Xcode bug, lots of people reporting it here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12602

UPDATE: Apple have now disabled submission to the App Store from builds later than Beta 6.

Answer (score 1):

I've had intermittent crashes in the past when uploading from a developer account set up for me by the client. In desperation they sent me the main account details and that worked (ridiculous I know)

Answer (score 1):

Upload it with Application Loader:

> from top bar menu > **Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader**

Comment: This allows you to upload the IPA. Quite a few steps missing, especially since the OP and others cannot export from the organizer.